# APEX: read from view but form insert or update in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a report that is populated from a view. I wish to edit some entries or add some entries but instead I want to save them in another table which this view represents. any help

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question. What exactly is the problem? What isn't working with a standard report and form?

Comment: Not sure (haven't tried it with an Apex tabular form), but if you want the report based on a view but new entries inserted into a different table, you might try an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view which does the insert. However, I'm not sure whether an ordinary Apex tabular form will allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to build the report on table and then change the query to select columns I want. I get to page source and changed the SQL I have to match the view I need.